# Cómo guardar al usuario sin ser repetido usando MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Necesito guardar un solo registro de cada usuario usando discordjs y mysql pero a la hora de guardarlos y que el usuario vuelva a entrar se repite en la base de datos y no he podido hacer que solo se guarde una vez el mismo usuario,muestro code

```js
router.get("/", auth, async function(req, res) {

    let client = req.client;
    
    const data = req.user;
    console.log(req.user);
    req.getConnection((err, connection) => {
          connection.query('INSERT INTO usuarios (username, id_user, avatar, discriminator) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [data.username, data.id, data.avatar, data.discriminator], (err, usuario) => {
        console.log(usuario)
      })
        res.render("perfil/index.ejs", {
          login: req.isAuthenticated() ? "si" : "no",
          status: req.isAuthenticated() ? "PERFIL" : "LOGIN",
          loginp: (req.isAuthenticated() ? true : false),
          ApiDiscord: client,
          user: req.user
        });
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo a nivel de base de datos diciéndole que el campo *username* es único:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios  ADD UNIQUE( username);
```